# set size of iPhone view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, resize, uistoryboardsegue

I am segueing to a view controller called SmallerVC. I want to set the size of SmallerVC to 300 X 300. So far I am not having much luck. I have tried the answers at the following link separately and then together, they don't work: [ios5 - size of modal view controller with storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052787/ios5-size-of-modal-view-controller-with-storyboard). I am using Xcode-5 and iOS-7. Has anyone successfully done this? I came to iOS with the prejudice that anything I can do on Android I should be able to do more easily on iOS. And so far iOS has been constantly disabusing me of that notion. Can such a simple thing be really so difficult?

To get to the button of things, I set my content view's color to clearColor. And sure enough, during transition it is clear, but upon transitioning a black background shows up that covers the whole screen. So my guess is I need to access and manipulate some sort of parent. Any ideas how I might do this?

**UPDATE: my code**

Here is the latest iteration of my code. The modal segue is set in storyboard.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"smaller_view_id"]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SmallerVC class]]) {
            UIViewController *container = (SmallerVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
            container.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

            id sourceController = segue.sourceViewController;
            UIView *destinationView = [container view];
            CGFloat x, y, w, h;
            x = 10;//destinationView.superview.frame.origin.x;
            y = 50;//destinationView.superview.frame.origin.y;
            w = 300;  // Your desired modal view width
            h = 300;  // Your desired modal view height
            destinationView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
            destinationView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
            destinationView.superview.center = [[sourceController view] center];
            [container setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
            [container setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
           // [sourceController presentViewController:container animated:YES completion:nil];
            NSLog(@"SEGUE CALL IS SEEN");
#pragma warning - pass in previous review data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of transition are you doing? Are you trying to show a modal view, pushing it to a navigation controller or what?

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff initially a modal view. But at this point I am open to suggestion. I want the view to be smaller and show the caller behind it: similar to how the AlertView behaves.

Comment: Then you probably want to configure the `modalPresentationStyle` of the VC you're trying to show. You'd want to use `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` or `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, and I don't think your background color can be `clearColor`, but feel free to try it out. EDIT: to be honest, I don't know how these work in iPhones, I usually work with iPads, so its behavior is probably different.

Comment: do you mind showing an example of how I would use UIModalPresentationFormSheet/UIModalPresentationPageSheet with/out a storyboard segue to resize my view controller? thanks. Also I am talking about a full-blow ViewController with ImageView, TextField, Button, etc. I just need it to be a smaller size than full-screen.

Comment: Sure, select your storyboard segue and select options like these: http://cdn.pqp.vc/segue_example.png

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff thanks but Xcode 5 does not seem to have these options. My options are: Identifier, style, transition, animate. Effectively, I am missing `Presentation` as my `style` is the same as your `segue`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Seems that's not available on Xcode 5. You can however do that in code, I guess. Something along the lines of `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{     ((UIViewController*)segue.destinationViewController).modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; }` should work.

Comment: should I subsequently set the size in code as well? So far setting modalPresentationStyle has made no difference.

Comment: I think you can achieve what you want by embedding the smaller view controller in a subview of the presenting view controller.

Comment: Try this lib, it is great replacement for the iOS Modal Sheet, it allows you to set the size of the displayed view controller: https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController

Comment: @KatedralPillon well, then the behavior is different on iPhone screens. In this case, like LevLandau said, you'd probably be better off adding subviews to your current VC instead of trying to show a modal.